# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int' when doing a python filter

Tags: python, filter

I had to do a simple problem in a coding test in which I had to find the maximum of a list of integers which were multiples of 3. The array passed to a function is a mix of multiples and non-multiples of 3.

This solution should have worked:

```py
def max_multiple_three(A):
    return list(filter(lambda i: i % 3 == 0, A))
```

But I get a TypeError:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

What is the reason? How do I resolve

Comment: I'd wager the issue isn't with your function but the list you are passing to the function.

Comment: At least one entry in `A` is a `list` and not an integer. You'll need to look at where `max_multiple_three` is called to determine why that is.